# view controller pushed from navigation controller is not displayed

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation view controller that pushes "viewController1" properly. Then, from "viewController1", goToApp function is called in order to push "appViewController". Function goToApp is executed but aplication remains at same view, "viewControlller1". How to push it? Thank you.

from viewController1:

```
 navigationViewController *theInstance = [[navigationViewController alloc] init];
    [theInstance goToApp];
```

in navigationViewController:

```
-(void)goToApp {

    appViewController *AppsViewController = [[appViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"appViewController" bundle:nil];

    [[self navController] pushViewController:AppsViewController animated:YES];

    [AppsViewController release];

}
```

goToApp executed but appViewController not launched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create a new UINavigationController in viewController1. You should get it through the property `navigationController`. That property will return the UINavigationController that has the UIViewController on it's stack (if any, so it can be nil).

```
UINavigationController * theInstance = self.navigationController;
[theInstance goToApp];
```

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html property navigationController.

Besides that, it is a better convention to name your pointers correctly to what they represent. I would suggest to rename `theInstance` to `currentNavigationController` or just `navigationController`.

Comment: Sorry but not understood. I am not creating a new navigation controller in viewController1. viewController1 calls a function implemented in navigationViewController (main nav controller). This function should push appViewController like I pushed previously viewController1.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood you question. It seems like you have made a complicated construction with multiple possible errors.

About the `navigationViewController * theInstance`, does it has a view in which it should push new `UIViewController`s? I think my previous answer still holds, in the sense that you create a new `UINavigationController` instead of reusing it. In `viewController1` you get a new (and thereby other) `UINavigationController` then the one that pushed `viewController1`.